# Do I need three train depots for a triple-station in OpenTTD?

Tags: openttd

If I continue these rails to another three-station without connecting them, will I need a total of three train depots?

[image]

Comment: There is some good information on the wiki about [building depots](https://wiki.openttd.org/en/Manual/Building%20depots#where-do-i-place-a-depot).  Looking at the images may give you an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If you're not connecting the tracks to each other, each track will need its own depot so that the train can go for repairs, and so you can get the train onto the track in the first place.